# innodb_log_file_size not upating even after changing my.cnf

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Hello team this is my first post here,

Server version: 10.0.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 Ubuntu 16.04

I am trying to import large db  and half way I get the error to increase Size of InnoDB Redo Log Files so I do follow this steps

```
mysql -uroot -p... -e"SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0"
service mysql stop
```

change my.cnf to

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

# innodb
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 32M
```

and then restart mysql

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile[01] /tmp
service mysql start
```

but still I see

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_log_file_size';
+----------------------+----------+
| Variable_name        | Value    |
+----------------------+----------+
| innodb_log_file_size | 50331648 |
+----------------------+----------+
```

my values are not updated ? can you please let me know is there anything I am missing ?

Comment: You'd normally put the innodb configuration in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/innodb.conf under a `[mariadb]` section. I suspect that `/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf` is read but not the my.cnf file you quoted based on the comments there. By setting to 32M you've actually decreased the size from 50M. Suggest something like 250M. Your buffer pool is also possibly too small depending on your import size.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes I did notice that I am setting it to 32m, however under l\mysql\mariadb.conf.d I have 50-client.cnf, 50-mysql-clients.cnf, 50-mysqld_safe.cnf, 50-server.cnf these files should I be creating innodb.conf file ?

Comment: 50-server.cnf would sound like a good place to put it.

Comment: was able to solve this issue by chaining .cnf in mysql/mariadb.config.d

Answer (score 1):

The buffer_pool_size seems rather low.  How much RAM do you have?

`innodb_log_file_size` can be virtually any size.  Make it as big as `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

But, and this may be the problem, the setting must be in a section started by

```
[mysqld]
```

See also: https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/31/what-is-a-big-innodb_log_file_size/